# Newsletter observer for Magento 2.2.2

Tags: event-observer, magento2.2, newsletter

Before 2.2 I made a small plugin to sync email subscription with our provider like the following and everything is working in ect/frontend/events.xml

I created my observer like this :

```
<event name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before">
    <observer name="VendorName_newsletter_subscriber" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\Newsletter" />
</event>
```

and in my VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\Newsletter.php

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $event->getSubscriber();
    $customerEmail = $customer->getSubscriberEmail();
    $customerName = $customer->getFirstname();
    $customerLastname = $customer->getLastname();
    $customerId = $customer->getId();
    $checkSubscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
    if ($checkSubscriber->isSubscribed()) {
        // Customer is subscribed
        //sync with Sendinblue
        ....
    }
    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Welcome back beloved customer %1 !', $customer->getCustomer()));
}
```

everything was working as expected but now I got a "null" on my $customer variable.

I didn't find anything on dev-doc about changes. Has there been an update I've missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. It will help you to get customer object.

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
)
{
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

$customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
```

**OR** - To get Customer using `$observer`

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work also...

I got a 
    
    Call to a member function getSubscriberEmail() on null

error, so as I started...

Comment: did you try both options?

Comment: YEs, got it ot work right now

       $customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
        $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
        $customerName = $customer->getFirstname();
        $customerLastname = $customer->getLastname();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();

        $checkSubscriber = $this->subscriber->loadByEmail($customerEmail);

Thanks